# Does Parallels use proprietary drivers or virtualization technology?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualization, macbook-pro, parallels

This might not be the right place to ask and even a bit of a vague question but I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I'm running a MacBook Pro (2016) and I've been using VirtualBox in order to run Ubuntu (18) VM's in the past. These VM's were always a bit buggy and I thought this had to do with lacking virtualization / driver software.

I've recently purchased Parallels and noticed that Ubuntu (20) is working perfectly. The graphics are crisp and the system is really responsive.

Does this have to do with the (proprietary) drivers / virtualization that Parallels pre-installs on the Virtual machine?

I'm asking because ideally I'd like to keep using VirtualBox since it is open source and I'm wondering what makes the difference.

Comment: Is your question about VirtualBox or Parallels?

Comment: I was just wondering if I could get the same smooth experience in VirtualBox with the help of a toolbox or set of drivers or anything or if they simply are only available with proprietary packages (like Parallels, which I just happened to have a year-subscription for). So my question is not about either of the two specifically but about the differences between them. Thanks for your answer btw. The link was really helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both VirtualBox and Parallels use emulated devices for all devices,
except for the CPU.

The performance you see is determined by the quality of these virtual devices
to interface to the native host devices.
In other words, how efficient are their drivers.

Especially for the crisp graphics, you will find in the article
[How does Parallels Desktop for Mac work with Mac video cards?](https://kb.parallels.com/122807):

> Parallels Desktop has no access to the Mac's device's physical graphics cards. Instead, Parallels Display Adapter driver (which is part of the Parallels Tools installation) interfaces with virtual hardware and provides 3D acceleration features. The actual acceleration is achieved by translating Direct X commands from the guest OS to the OpenGL API on the macOS side.

According to your experience, this translation between virtual and
physical devices is done in a very efficient way,
using well-written proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 0):

> I've recently purchased Parallels and noticed that Ubuntu (20) is
> working perfectly. The graphics are crisp and the system is really
> responsive.  ...    Does this have to do with the (proprietary)
> drivers / virtualization that Parallels pre-installs on the Virtual
> machine?

Yes, I think that is broadly true.

**Note:**  Your question is about Parallels but I interpreted it more broadly about top grade products. I answered with my experience about VMware (vs. Virtual Box) and some experience with Hyper-V.

I use VMware Workstation in Windows and have a LOT less difficulty than members here that use Virtual Box.

I have a machine with Hyper-V, and I think VMware is easier to use and more flexible along with smoother operation than Hyper-V.  Hyper-V still works fine and graphics are good, but VMware is easier to use, which is important.

I have many VMs, but the ones I use all the time in VMware are Windows 7, Kali 2021 and Ubuntu 20.04. All three are very smooth and graphics in the VMs are excellent.

I work inside Kali regularly.

VMware uses proprietary drivers and the VMware Tools (essential for virtual machines) and this produces excellent results.

Professional tools (of many kinds) that charge license fees and provide support are often better than free tools.

So, long answer to say, Yes.

Comment: The post is about Parallels, not VMware.

Comment: True but I offered overall advice about top notch paid virtualization products vs. free. So I think that fits. Please let me know if my answer should be deleted. Thank you.

Comment: Your decision to make, I just think you should clarify this part.

Comment: Thank you. I added a large clarification. Good idea.